# Decrease the width of too long table

Tags: tables

How can I decrease the width of a tool long table?

```tex
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[font={normalsize}]{caption}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Summary of the relevant state of the art}
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
\hline
 Independent variables & Target variable & Data records & Train/test(\%) & Model & Metrics & Reference \\ \hline
 Critical energy release rate , unnotched strength, young modulus, hole diameter, width, stacking sequences& Tensile strength & 10000 & 90/10 & XGBoost, Random Forests, Gaussian Processes and Artificixxxxxxxxal Networks & RMSE = 0.005 &  Furtado et al. furtado2021methodology\\
 Young modulus, Damagxxxxxx strain, saturation strain, damage curve angle& force-pin opening displacement curve & 15000 & 70/30 & Theory-guided neural network architecture, recurrent neural networks wxxxxx Short-Term Memory (LSTM) architecture  & RMSE=0.266 & Reiner et al. reiner2021machine \\
 particle size, cuxxxxxx,power level, volume fraction, curing angle& optimum tensile strength  & 46 &  78.26/21.74 & Adaptixxxxxxxrk-based Fuzzy Inference System , Artificial Neural Networks  & RMSE=0.0307, MAE=0.0098, $R^2$=0.99, RMSE=0.0827 & Okafor et al. okafor2021evaluation \\
 crack position , pattern type , loading angle,
sample thickness, crack length& Fracture toughness & 200 & 80/20 & KNN, DT, RF, SVM & RMSE=35.49, MAE=26.48, EP=7.45, $R^2$=0.95 &  Balcıoğlu et al. \cite{balciouglu2021comparison}\\
stacking sequence, thickness & buckling load, ultimate load & 4367 & 75/25  & ANN & RMSE =  3.03E-06 & Sun et alsun2021prediction\\
 Elastic modulus, Poisson's ratio, fiber volume fraction, fiber aspect ratio& stiffness & 1015 & 75/25 & ANN & RMSE= 0.03 & Breuer et al.breuer2021prediction \\
 fiber content , hold time, molding pressure, and hold temperature&  Impact toughness&30  & 66.6/33.3&Gaussian process regression, DT, Ensemble, SVR, LR  & $R^2$=0.96, RMSE= 0.4369, MAE=0.3265 & Zhang et al. zhang2021machine \\
 fiber content , hold time, molding pressure, and hold temperature& Tensile strength &  30& 66.6/33.3 & Gaussian process regression, DT, Ensemble, SVR, LR & $R^2$=0.99, RMSE= 0.08, MAE=0.06 &  Zhang et al. zhang2021machine \\
 Fiber diameter, Embedded length, Young’s modulus, Poisson’s ratio, Loading rate, Preparation and test temperature & Maximum force , Interfacial shear strength & 922 & 88/12& LR, BR, EN, SVR, GBR, ANN & RMSE=0.131, $R^2$=0.735 & Yin et al. yin2021machine \\
 Length, Width, Thickness, Hole configuration, Circle radius, Hole radius, Force, Stacking Sequence&  Maximum tensile Stress & 8960 &  1/99 & Stacked models & $R^2$=0.97  & This study \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{SART}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend your example to a full minimal example such that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Extend means full version sir?

Comment: There is no document class, or preamble here. So we cannot test your code without adding stuff to your example. The stuff we add might not be the same as you have in your document, so it is better that you provide the example.

Comment: I edited but I do not know hoe to arrange correcly

Comment: Note that your example does not compile as there is a missing `\cite{` in the second row of the table.

Comment: I think now is ok

Comment: Why are the first 5 columns of the data empty? That is an extreme waste of space. Instead of trying to cram this into a table, you should perhaps take a moment and think whether there is a better way to convey this information to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the overlong entries; adding some vertical space between rows will help in making the table fit.

I added some other advice, look for `<---`.

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle}
%\usepackage{geometry}% <--- use the style elsarticle wants
%\usepackage{epsfig}% <--- obsolete
%\usepackage{latexsym}% <--- obsolete
\usepackage[font={normalsize}]{caption}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
%\usepackage{setspace}% <--- use the style elsarticle wants
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}% <--- use the style elsarticle wants
%\usepackage{sectsty}% <--- not with elsarticle
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{float}% <--- don't use [H]
%\usepackage{indentfirst}% <--- use the style elsarticle wants
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{subfigure}% <--- obsolete and incompatible with subcaption

% packages for tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{graphics}% <--- obsolete
%\usepackage{caption}% <--- duplication

\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt} % <--- should be local, anyway

\caption{Summary of the relevant state of the art}
\label{SART}% <--- the label refers to the caption

\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccl@{}}
\toprule
% headers
\splitcell{Independent \\ variables} &
\splitcell{Target \\ variable} &
\splitcell{Data \\ records} &
Train/test &
Model &
Metrics &
Reference
\\
\midrule
% body
&  &  &  &  & 
RMSE = 0.005 &
Furtado et al. \cite{furtado2021methodology}
\\ \addlinespace
&  &  &  &  &
RMSE = 0.266 &
Reiner et al. \cite{reine}
\\ \addlinespace
&  &  &  &  &
  \splitcell{RMSE = 0.0307 \\ MAE = 0.0098 \\ $R^2$ = 0.0827} &
  Okafor et al. \cite{okafor2021evaluation}
\\ \addlinespace
&  &  &  &  &
  \splitcell{RMSE = 35.49 \\ MAE = 26.48 \\ EP = 7.45 \\ $R^2$ = 0.95} &
  Balcıoğlu et al. \cite{balciouglu2021comparison}
\\ \addlinespace
&  &  &  &  &
  RMSE = 3.03E$-06$ &
  Sun et al.\cite{prediction}
\\ \addlinespace
&  &  &  &  &
  RMSE = 0.03 &
  Breuer et al.\cite{bre21prediction}
\\ \addlinespace
&  &  &  &  &
  \splitcell{$R^2$ = 0.96 \\ RMSE = 0.4369 \\ MAE = 0.3265} &
  Zhang et al. \cite{zhang2021machine}
\\ \addlinespace
&  &  &  &  &
  \splitcell{$R^2$ = 0.99 \\ RMSE = 0.08 \\ MAE = 0.06} &
  Zhang et al. \cite{zhang2021machine}
\\ \addlinespace
&  &  &  &  &
  \splitcell{RMSE = 0.131 \\ $R^2$ = 0.735} &
  Yin et al. \cite{machine}
\\ \addlinespace
&  &  &  &  &
  $R^2$ = 0.97  &
  This study
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also fixed all inconsistencies of spaces around =.

Comment: Thank you so much really. I edited the question such that now could you please look at it. The empty parts are really wide.

Comment: @AhmadTurani Please, revert. I was expecting short data for the first columns. As it stands, it is really impossible to make a meaningful table from that data: you're trying to pack too much information in a short space. I suggest to use a section with subsections.

Comment: Ok. If i want to split the ""model"" part what should I do? instead of \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccl@{}} ? I mean I want to write in a column in each row. how should I do that? Like the part metrics and references.

Comment: You did not splitpart the metrics part but you could split it in table. i could not do it for model section for instance

Comment: Ok I got all. now my table is fit but it is too long and it goes to the next page out of margin. how can I make it correct to fit in length?